# How was the house set on fire?

Tags: layers-of-fear

If you've played the game, you'd stumble across multiple references to the fact that the house was set on fire.

One was a newspaper article which told of the news, and you even come to the part of home where you're walking in the attic-like part of the home and beneath you - you can see fire.

What's the truth about the fire? What were the motives?